# getting compile time error in main program itself in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I have been using spring integration to develop a mail box listener using pop 3 protocol so it will listen to a mailbox and will read all the mails using pop3 protocol
but i have develop a  main class in which i am getting the error the error that i am getting is on the below line

```
inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
```

and it is complie time error indicating that `The method subscribe(MessageHandler) in the type AbstractSubscribableChannel is not applicable for the arguments (new MessageHandler(){})`

below is the main class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;


public class GmailInboundPop3AdapterTestApp {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GmailInboundPop3AdapterTestApp.class);

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/test1/src/main/resources/gmail-pop3-config.xml");
        DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);
        inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                logger.info("Message: " + message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please advise how to overcome from this error itself

also below is my xml

```
<int:channel id="receiveChannel" />
    <!-- replace 'userid and 'password' wit the real values -->
    <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
                        store-uri="pop3://[userid]:[password]@pop.gmail.com/INBOX"
                        channel="receiveChannel"
                        should-delete-messages="true"
                        auto-startup="true"
                        java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
            <!-- Will poll every 20 seconds -->
            <int:poller fixed-rate="20000"/>

    </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.port">995</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</prop>
    </util:properties>
</beans>
```

Comment: Looks ok. Import statements are in place. Maybe you have another class (or interface) named `MessageHandler` in the same package as the main class? If not, how are you compiling? Additionally, please add the annotation `@Override` in front of the `handleMessage` method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CLASSPATH for the old Spring Integration version. It is based on the `spring-messaging` since 4.0. So, version < 4.0 doesn't accepts `org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler` - it must be `org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler`.

So, from my perspective it's just a mix of versions in the classpath.

Comment: Always refer to the [migration guides](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki) when changing Spring Integration versions. And always try to use the latest version; scroll down on the [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) for version information.